# Fourier Series Derivative of saw tooth-like function

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, derivatives, fourier-series, piecewise-continuity

So I have this periodic signal x(t),
$$x(t)=\begin{cases}
5t & \text{ if } x \in [0.2,0.4]\\
-10t & \text{ if } x \in [0.4,0.5] \\
0 & \text{ if } x \in [0.5, 0.6]
\end{cases}$$
and I was trying to calculate the regular Fourier Series coefficients.

One way to do it is by using the regular expression:
$$a_n = \frac{1}{(b-a)}\int_{a}^{b}x(t)e^{-i2\pi/(b-a)nt}dt \ (1)$$

But I decided to try something different, namely using the derivative of x(t). So if we consider $$x(t)' = \begin{cases}
5 & \text{ if } x \in ]0.2,0.4[\\
-10 & \text{ if } x \in ]0.4,0.5[ \\
0 & \text{ if } x \in ]0.5, 0.6[
\end{cases}=\sum_{n} b_ne^{-i2\pi/(b-a)nt}$$ we have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}(\sum_{n} a_ne^{-i2\pi/(b-a)nt})=\sum_{n} b_ne^{-i2\pi/(b-a)nt} \\
\Rightarrow b_n = [-i2\pi/(b-a)n]\cdot a_n \ (2)$$

The problem comes when I try to calculate $b_n$ using (1) and then with (2) retrieve $a_n$, as the $a_n$ calculated by this method doesn't coincide with the one directly calculated by (1).

Am I doing any supposition wrong? I'm guessing maybe the fact $x'(t)$ is not defined everywhere could be problematic? Any help is welcomed.

Comment: And the error isn’t just in the constant ($a_0$) component? Note that your trick basically amounts to integrating the expression for $a_n$ by parts.

Comment: The problem comes from the points where you join the expressions as when you integrate by parts the "derivative" (as it is not quite the derivative since the original function is discontinuous there so the true derivative involves some Dirac measures at those points) you get extra terms there which do not cancel out; it is easier to just bite the bullet and compute the Fourier coefficients of the original function directly by splitting the integral in 3 parts and integrating by parts on each

Comment: @user7530 I don't think so

Comment: @Conrad where do the extra terms come from?

Comment: When you compute the Fourier coefficients of a piecewise function and split the periodicity interval into a few pieces and do integration by parts, the evaluation terms at pieces do not cancel out since sine and cosine get multiplied by different numbers at the right vs left on each piece, so while the integrals that result give indeed $1/n$ of the original coefficients, those extra evaluation terms have to be considered too - formally they appear as integrals of Dirac measures